# Pass the current Model down to a more specific shape

Tags: orchardcms

TL;DR: How do I pass the model down into the next shape?

I have modified the Orchard.Search modules search results view in my theme (`Views\Orchard.Search\Search\Index.cshtml`), and split it out into several scenarios. I test for one result and just redirect straight through and test for no search terms and multiple search search results.

I would like to put these scenarios in separate `.cshtml` views but these specialised shapes need access to the main search result model (`@model Orchard.Search.ViewModels.SearchViewModel`).

I tried using `Arguments.From` to make a dynamic object which works but then I have to cast everything in the view back to its correct data type because the next shape down thinks every property on its model is of type `dynamic`.

Instead I've tried to figure out how to just pass the whole `Model` to the next shape:

```
@if (HasMultipleResults())
{
    var shapeFactory = (IShapeFactory)New;
    // this doesn't work
    var multipleResultsShape = (dynamic)shapeFactory.Create("Search_MultipleResults", Model);
    @Display(multipleResultsShape);
    return;
}
```

I haven't found a way to get it working yet, can anyone educate me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first argument of the dynamic method is a type, then this will be used as the model.

`New.YourShape(typeof(YourType))`

See this video for the details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKLjtCIs4GU&feature=youtu.be&t=1127

Comment: I tried this `var multipleResultsShape = New.Search_MultipleResults(typeof(Orchard.Search.ViewModels.SearchViewModel), Model); @Display(multipleResultsShape);` but it throws `Invalid base type for shape: Orchard.Search.ViewModels.SearchViewModel`.

Comment: Try to make it inherit from `Shape`

Comment: I'm just overriding the search results view from the Orchard.Search module in my Theme. I guess I can't use that technique this time then without modifying the built in orchard modules?